# How to change color of a svg by using a get query parameter

Tags: svg

I came across this svg https://tailwindui.com/img/logos/workflow-mark.svg (the default is black) which then can change color using

https://tailwindui.com/img/logos/workflow-mark.svg?color=white

I like to adopt the same method. How do I do this?

If it's important, I'm using Django as backend and Nginx as my webserver and bunnyCDN as my CDN provider

Answer (score 0):

I expect there is a script on the server - possibly triggered by the `/img` part of the URL - that takes a template SVG and uses search and replace to change the colour.

For example, the template SVG may be the default black SVG.  Then when you spefify `color=white`, it replaces ever occurrence of `fill="#000"` with `fill="#fff"`.